# Why does my recently installed app keep downgrading?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, downgrade

Not sure here is the best community for this issue, sorry if it isn't.

As a developer, I am proposing some promo codes from the App Store Connect website to download a non-released version of my app (available once Apple validated the review).

On some iPhones, the code is working fine: it automatically starts downloading the new version, but then once the download is finished, it automatically downgrades the app back to the previous installed version.

The problem can be reproduced after the iPhone has been restarted or with a new generated code.

Any idea why?

Comment: Could it be something like the app was built using Cordova vs Capacitor or something like that?

Comment: No, it's a native app 100% coded in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Are the iPhones that don't work older ones? This issue could be caused by running code written on the newest versions of Xcode on older devices (such as iOS 7-8), which are not backwards compatible with the newest versions of Xcode?

Comment: Not related to this: it is doing the same on my own iPhone X iOS 13.X which has no problem running the app otherwise.

Comment: Have you updated the app, and if you did, did it downgrade again?

Comment: Yes: to me and several other users I send codes too. It does get installed, then iOS automatically install "back" the previous version ~10s after the update finished.